# How to install Wine application on particular disk

Tags: software-installation, wine, files, filesystem

I’m new to Ubuntu so I don’t know much on how the file system works.
I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my 256GB SSD and I have mounted a 1TB drive in my media directory. My question is how can I install a large AAA game (through Wine) so that the folders for the game are on the 1TB HDD?

I know that in Windows it’s easy, just select that dir as install dir in the installation wizard. I heard something that it cannot be done because of the way the file system is used in Linux. But I refuse to believe that we live in a world where Linux can’t do something Windows can...

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty easy.

All apps installed through Wine go to the `/home/$USER/.wine/` directory. So the solution to your problem is to make a symbolic link (something like a shortcut in Windows) to point to somewhere on your 1 TB drive.

Take a look below and craft it to your needs:

```
ln -s /media/your-disk  /home/$USER/.wine
```

You can also do it by mouse right clicking on the destination folder and selecting "Make Link". Then just move it to your home dir and rename to `.wine`. That's all.

EDIT:
as @muru noticed, an alternative way is to change the `WINEPREFIX` environmental variable. In this approach simply add to the `.bashrc` line:

```
export WINEPREFIX=/media/your-disk/wine-apps
```

Comment: +1 '...unless the OP already *has* a `/home/$USER/.wine` directory, in which case it'll be slighly trickier. But this is the way to go.

Comment: Probably better to do `export WINEPREFIX=/media/your-disk/some/folder`, instead of replacing `~/.wine`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method, which does not require symlinks, is to set the `WINEPREFIX` environment variable to point to the disk.

Add the following to `/etc/environment`:

```
WINEPREFIX=<path-to-disk>
```

This has the added advantage of being able to have multiple wine prefixes, just set the `WINEPREFIX` to point at another directory. This can be particularly useful for switching between 64 and 32 bit, which I tend to require a lot for games.

If you are installing the game with steam, you could save yourself a lot of effort by adding it as a steam download location.

Comment: `/etc/environment` should not contain `export`, only key-value pairs.

Comment: @OrangeDog you're right, I have updated the anwer

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one of two ways:

- Wine should expose the Linux root directory (`/`) as the `Z:` drive. In that case, change the installation directory in the installer to be something like `Z:/media/petar/1tbdrive` (or wherever your 1TB drive is mounted).
- Open `winecfg` and navigate to the Drives tab to create a new drive mapping for your external drive. This way, your 1TB HDD (or a subdirectory of it) will be exposed to the game's installer as a separate Windows drive.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't know about it. Thanks!